# How do I extract a random sample of rows my array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indices

I have a numpy array called input_north which has shape (823886, 13)

I want to randomly select 82388 rows from this array and store them in another array called truth. However, I also want to delete the randomly sampled rows from original input_north array.

Here is what I have done but its not working correctly:

```
# first i make 82388 random indices between 1-823886 
indices = np.random.choice(823886, 82388)

# then I use the indices to create my truth array
truth = input_north[indicies, :]

# I then create a new array with the truth rows deleted
input = np.delete(input_north, indices, 0)
```

When I do this, I get a truth array of the correct size (82388, 13) with a random sample of rows. But, the input array comes out with a shape of (745496, 13). This means that not all of the rows extracted to the truth array have been deleted in the input array as it contains around 4000 more rows than I want. How can I extract the rows from my inut_north data and delete the rows which I have extracted?

Comment: add `replace=False` argument to `np.random.choice`? Using a [MRE] you could easier see what is happening in your code. Try to avoid variable names that shadow built-in functions.

Comment: BTW: You are choosing from indices between `0 - 823885` (including 0 but excluding 823886)

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Thank you, that has solved my problem! And noted, I'll change that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try it this way

```py
import numpy as np

# create a array like:
# [1,1,1,1,...]
# [2,2,2,2,...]
# [3,3,3,3,...]
# [...]
# [N,N,N,N,...]

N = 100

data = np.ones((N, 13))
data[:] = data * np.arange(1,data.shape[0]+1)[:,None]
data = data.astype(np.int)

print(data)

# not perutate the array
np.random.shuffle(data)

print(data)

# now choose truth and input
split = 85
input = data[:split]
truth = data[split:]


print("input.shape",input.shape)
print("truth.shape",truth.shape)
```

```py
input.shape (85, 13)
truth.shape (15, 13)
```

Comment: Thank you! Using replace = false has solved it. I tried this method however using the numpy.random.shuffle() function on my numpy array didn't work, and gave a NoneType answer with no data. Not sure why this is?

Comment: Shuffle works inplace... so no you cannot do data = np.random.shuffle(). Did the code above did the correct thing when you executed it?